# Stretching an SVG Image when converting it to a PNG/JPEG using batik rasterizer?

Tags: java, svg, png, jpeg, batik

I am currently trying to render some .svg images to .png/.jpg images using the batik rasterizer library.

If I try to convert an image within its aspect ratio, everything works fine, but when I try to change the aspect ratio(let's say the vector image is quadratic, e.g. 32x32 and I want to stretch it to 64x32), it gives me an output Image that has a size of of 64x32 pixels with the vector being drawn in the middle of the image as a 32x32 area. THis is the code I'm using:

```
PNGTranscoder transcoder = new PNGTranscoder();

transcoder.addTranscodingHint(PNGTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH, width); //64px
transcoder.addTranscodingHint(PNGTranscoder.KEY_HEIGHT, height); //32px
```

Also, I would like to stretch an image until it has a width of 128 pixels, independet from its height, using the transcoding hint `PNGTranscoder.KEY_MAXWIDTH`, but the ranscoder just does not scale the image up to this width.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: as a workaround you might want to do the scaling by wrapping your svg with a transform="scale( ...)" clause

Answer (score 0):

ref: [How to ignore proportionality when scaling SVG images using Apache Batik?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111500/how-to-ignore-proportionality-when-scaling-svg-images-using-apache-batik)

`rootElement.setAttribute("preserveAspectRatio", "none");`

Comment: After more than eleven and a half years, I'm not sure whether the OP will be reading your answer and for others who may land on this webpage because they have similar issues, will they know what `rootElement` is?