# How to ignore proportionality when scaling SVG images using Apache Batik?

Tags: java, apache, svg, scaling, batik

I am currently trying to creating a custom JComponent (ViewerComponent) that scales and displays a SVG image using [apache batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/). Currently the ViewerComponent scales the SVG image proportionally; however, I would like for it to scale to fit the size of the component, ignoring proportionality. The code below shows a simple test I have written for the ViewerComponent. How can I modify it the ViewerComponent to behave as I mentioned above?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import org.apache.batik.swing.*;
import org.apache.batik.swing.gvt.*;
import org.apache.batik.util.*;
import org.w3c.dom.svg.*;

public final class View extends JPanel {

    public static final Dimension VIEW_SIZE = new Dimension(2000, 2000);
    public static final Dimension WINDOW_SIZE = new Dimension(600, 600);
    public static final String BACKGROUND_IMAGE
            = "file:///Users/home/Desktop/wiki.svg";

    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private ViewerComponent canvas;

    View() throws URISyntaxException {
        setUpGUI();
        createViewerBasedOnViewportSize();
    }

    private void setUpGUI() throws HeadlessException {
        setUpView();
        setUpScrollPane();
        setUpFrame();
    }

    private void setUpView() {
        this.setPreferredSize(VIEW_SIZE);
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    private void setUpScrollPane() {
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(this);
    }

    private void setUpFrame() throws HeadlessException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SVG Viewer Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(scrollPane);
        frame.setPreferredSize(WINDOW_SIZE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                adjustBackgroundComponentScale();
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    private void adjustBackgroundComponentScale() {
        if (canvas != null) {
            Dimension windowSize = calculateWindowSize();
            canvas.setFinalViewerSize(windowSize);
        }
    }

    private void createViewerBasedOnViewportSize() throws URISyntaxException {
        Dimension windowSize = calculateWindowSize();
        URI uri = retrieveURI();
        createViewer(uri, windowSize);
    }

    private Dimension calculateWindowSize() {
        final JViewport vp = (JViewport) getParent();
        final Dimension windowSize = vp.getVisibleRect().getSize();
        return windowSize;
    }

    private URI retrieveURI() throws URISyntaxException {
        URI uri = new URI(BACKGROUND_IMAGE);
        return uri;
    }

    void createViewer(final URI uri,
            final Dimension preferredSize) {
        canvas = new ViewerComponent(uri);
        canvas.addGVTTreeRendererListener(new GVTTreeRendererAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void gvtRenderingCompleted(final GVTTreeRendererEvent e) {
                canvas.setFinalViewerSize(preferredSize);
                canvas.revalidate();
                canvas.removeGVTTreeRendererListener(this);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (canvas != null) {
            setAndPaintViewer(g);
        }
    }

    private void setAndPaintViewer(Graphics g) {
        Graphics backgroundGraphics = g.create();
        try {
            setBackgroundComponentLocation(backgroundGraphics);
            canvas.paint(backgroundGraphics);
            repaint();
        } finally {
            backgroundGraphics.dispose();
        }
    }

    private void setBackgroundComponentLocation(Graphics g) {
        final JViewport vp = (JViewport) getParent();
        final Point viewPosition = vp.getViewPosition();
        g.translate(viewPosition.x, viewPosition.y);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new View();
                } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}

class ViewerComponent extends JSVGCanvas {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Dimension originalSize = null;

    public Dimension getOriginalSize() {
        return new Dimension(originalSize);
    }

    public void setFinalViewerSize(final Dimension size) {
        final JSVGCanvas canvas = this;
        canvas.setPreferredSize(size);
        canvas.setMySize(size);
        canvas.setSize(size);
    }

    public void setDraftViewerSize(final Dimension size) {
        setFinalViewerSize(size);
    }

    public void setFinalViewerSize(final float zoom) {
        int scaledWidth = (int) (originalSize.width * zoom);
        int scaledHeight = (int) (originalSize.height * zoom);
        setFinalViewerSize(new Dimension(scaledWidth, scaledHeight));
    }

    public ViewerComponent(final URI uri) {
        super(null, false, false);
        setDocumentState(ALWAYS_STATIC);
        setSize(1, 1);
        setRecenterOnResize(true);
        addGVTTreeRendererListener(new GVTTreeRendererAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void gvtRenderingStarted(final GVTTreeRendererEvent e) {
                super.gvtRenderingStarted(e);
                final SVGDocument document = getSVGDocument();
                final SVGSVGElement rootElement = document.getRootElement();
                final SVGLength width = rootElement.getWidth().getBaseVal();
                final SVGLength height = rootElement.getHeight()
                        .getBaseVal();
                float defaultWidth = (float) Math.ceil(width.getValue());
                float defaultHeigth = (float) Math.ceil(height.getValue());
                if (defaultWidth == 1f && defaultHeigth == 1f) {
                    defaultWidth = 200;
                    defaultHeigth = 200;
                }
                originalSize = new Dimension((int) defaultWidth,
                        (int) defaultHeigth);
                if ("".equals(rootElement.getAttributeNS(null,
                        SVGConstants.SVG_VIEW_BOX_ATTRIBUTE))) {
                    rootElement.setAttributeNS(null,
                            SVGConstants.SVG_VIEW_BOX_ATTRIBUTE, "0 0 "
                            + defaultWidth + " " + defaultHeigth);
                }
                setSize(originalSize);
                removeGVTTreeRendererListener(this);
            }
        });
        setURI(uri.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (originalSize == null) {
            return new Dimension(1, 1);
        }
        return super.getPreferredSize();
    }

}
```

Comment: I used your code to display an SVG File. Can you tell me how to change the code to display an SVGDocument instead of an SVG File? (the SVGDocument was created programmatically and does not seem to have an URI).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to set the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute to `none`.  So it will be something like:

```
rootElement.setAttribute("preserveAspectRatio", "none");
```

I haven't used the batik library this way myself, but that's the DOM way of achieving this result.